# Cтранное значение указателя

Tags: c++

Вопрос: почему значение указателя (`pChar = muэ`), указатель это же целый тип, а тут буквы какие-то. Помогите разобраться почему такое поведение.

Код:

```
//4. указатель на указатель на char
typedef char * myPointerChar;
typedef myPointerChar * myPointerPointerChar; //char**

int main()
{
    myPointerChar pChar = /*&ch3*/ new char('m');
    myPointerPointerChar ppChar = &pChar;
    std::cout << "myPointerChar pChar = " << pChar << " ;*myPointerChar *pChar = " << *pChar << "\n";
    std::cout << "myPointerPointerChar ppChar = " << ppChar << " ;*myPointerPointerChar *ppChar = " << *ppChar << "  ;**myPointerPointerChar **ppChar = " << **ppChar << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Выводимое значение:

```
myPointerChar pChar = muэ ;*myPointerChar *pChar = m
myPointerPointerChar ppChar = 0x61fe7c ;*myPointerPointerChar *ppChar = muэ  ;**myPointerPointerChar **ppChar = m
```

Вопрос: почему значение указателя (`pChar = muэ`), указатель это же целый тип, а тут буквы какие-то. Помогите разобраться почему такое поведение.

Comment: Такое поведение у 2 IDE: у QtCreator и VisualStudio 2017

Comment: Манипулятор std::hex не меняет ситуацию...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все есть байты и ничего кроме байтов.
Дальше начинается интерпретация байтов: в целое число, в строку, в исполняемый код, в байт-код и так далее.

Оператор new(), если грубо говорить, выделяет память и возвращает, к примеру, 4 байта, в которых заключен адрес этой памяти. Если они интерпретируются как число, там будет, к примеру, 0x30303030. А если эти же самые байты интерпретировать как строку - "0000".

У вас выделяется память под один байт. При выводе из указателя берется адрес этой выделенной памяти и оттуда выводится строка. Ожидается, что строка терминируется нулем, но явно вы этот ноль нигде не пишете в память, вот и выводится два символа с мусором.

Comment: то есть как не инициализирована: pChar - получает адрес в куче char('m'); ppChar - получает адрес указателя - pChar; Или у меня затмение в голове? Тип же известен компилятору - указатель, а раз указатель, то и представление должно быть соответствующее.

Comment: @sakton не, это у меня затмение :-) Терминирующего нуля нет, вот и появляется два мусорных символа.

Comment: если добавлю терм ноль - то будет уже строка char[], я строку не прошу, а прошу адрес указателя

Comment: printf ("0x%X\n", pChar) попробуйте.

Comment: Подозреваю перегрузку оператора "<<" и, как следствие, различное поведение для различных типов данных.

Comment: Все верно. Указатель на Char интерпретируется, началом массива символов.